# Inserting into DB2 database from SQL Server stored procedure succeeds, but wrapping the same procedure using Entity Framework fails

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, stored-procedures, db2

I need to be able to insert rows into a set of tables in a DB2 database from a Microsoft SQL Server database. I created stored procedures that can insert rows into the DB2 database using a linked server, referencing the target tables by their 4 part names. These procedures work and I am able to insert records by calling them in SQL Server Management Studio.

The schemas are different between the two databases, so I am using a C# program and Entity Framework wrap these stored procedures to help me perform the mapping. When running my program an exception is thrown with the message

> The operation could not be performed because OLE DB provider "IBMDASQL" for linked server "LinkedServer" was unable to begin a distributed transaction

Running a SQL trace and replaying the commands created by Entity Framework in SQL Server Management Studio creates the desired records in DB2.

What am I missing here to get these stored procedure calls working from Entity Framework?

Comment: Do not use the driver ibmdasql.  See : https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ssw_ibm_i_71/rzaii/rzaiimts.htm

Answer (score 0):

My problem was solved by setting a configuration property in my database context.

> db.Configuration.EnsureTransactionsForFunctionsAndCommands = false;